# How to create multiple records in a firebase realtime path?

Tags: python, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fastapi

I am using a firebase real time database for a web application that I have written in python. One of my endpoints has the function that the client can load a csv file and subsequently each row of the csv will be converted to a record (node) in a specific path in the database (I simply read the csv and convert it to a list of dictionaries).
The problem is when I go to send the records to the database, I use the following code:

```
def create(self, path:str, data: Dict[str, Any]):
        return self.db.reference(path).push(data)

@router.post("/")
def create_alerts(file: UploadFile):
    try:
        data = convert_csv(file) # convert csv to dictionary list
        for alert in data:
            info_alert = alert
            info_alert["status"] = "not_validated"
            fb_client.create(settings.FB_PATH, info_alert) #create function defined above
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {"message": "Error creating document"}
    return {"message": "Document created"}
```

My problem is that the process takes a long time because the csv has many rows and for each row a call is made to the firebase api. I would like with a single call I could create a node for each dictionary-row in the path. So I tried this:

```
try:
        data = convert_csv(file)
        for alert in data:
            info_alert = alert
            info_alert["status"] = "not_validated"
        fb_client.create(settings.FB_PATH, info_alert)
```

(remove the last line of the cycle). But in this case it creates a single new node in the path with all the records.
Is there any way to create all a node in the path specified by each dictionary without needing to call in each record the api?

Update:

```
try:
    data = convert_csv(file)
    ref = fb_client.db.reference(settings.FB_PATH)
    nodes_data = {}
    for alert in data:
        info_alert = alert
        info_alert["status"] = "not_validated"
        new_post_ref = ref.push()
        post_id = new_post_ref.key
        nodes_data[post_id] = info_alert
    fb_client.create(settings.FB_PATH, nodes_data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return {"message": "Error creating document"}
return {"message": "Document created"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Firebase Admin SDK for Python, you can use the approach shown in the documentation on [getting the unique key generated by `push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push):

```
# Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
new_post_ref = posts_ref.push()

# Get the unique key generated by push()
post_id = new_post_ref.key
```

This snippet never actually makes a call to the database backend. Instead, the call to `push()` generates a key that is statistically guaranteed to be unique, and then the next line gets that key.

Using this approach, you can generate a key for each line int he CSV file, and then only send them to database one you got all of them (or at least a batch of them).

---

**Update**: it turns out the Python SDK works differently then the client-side SDKs here. From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db):

> The optional value argument can be used to provide an initial value for the child node. **If no value is provided, child node will have empty string as the default value.**

So the above approach indeed won't work. The workaround you mentioned in the comments is to generate your own UUIDs.

Comment: Hi Frank, I have been trying to implement this approach but have had no results. I have edited my question and put under "Update" my new code. I think it is still calling the api every time the line is traversed: new_post_ref = ref.push(). I get the feeling that every time the loop is traversed the api is called and creates a new node in the path "settings.FB_PATH" with the unique key and value " ". Therefore, the process is still as slow. Could you help me?

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling you might not be using the SDK thta I linked. Can you double check and confirm what specific library you're using to access Firebase?

Comment: Frank, I have been using the library: firebase-admin. So you mean another library?

Comment: You're still calling `push()` in your `create` function here: `self.db.reference(path).push(data)`. So any time you call that, you're adding an extra layer to the data. If you don't want to add that layer, don't call `push()` in `create`, but instead use `update` as shwon here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-update This will merge the new keys with any existing ones, as you've already ensured that each CSV line has a unique ID in your `nodes_data` at that point.

Comment: That's right, I had to use update instead of push in the create method. However, to generate the unique keys I had to use the python uuid module, because doing new_post_ref = posts_ref.push().key calls me to the database backend and creates a node with the key and empty string(""). In the end I got what I wanted, I create the data with a single call to the firebase api. I just have one question in my mind, am I losing something by using unique keys with uuid instead of firebase generated ones?

Comment: Firebase's keys are chronological (they embed the current timestamp in the first few characters), but that's about it. I'm surprised that `push()` would already create the key, as it's not supposed to do that in the SDKs - so I'm checking with one of the engineers of those SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for your help Frank, I will keep an eye out for you if any changes are made to the sdk to generate the ids.

Comment: I just confirmed with one of the engineers and updated my answer. We filed an internal issue to change this behavior to match the Firebase SDKs for other platforms, but that'll be a breaking change. :( For now, your workaround is probably best.